# Theano: Why does indexing fail in this case?

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I'm trying to get the max of a vector given a boolean value.

With Numpy:

```
>>> this = np.arange(10)
>>> this[~(this>=5)].max()
4
```

But with Theano:

```
>>> that = T.arange(10, dtype='int32')
>>> that[~(that>=5)].max().eval()
9
>>> that[~(that>=5).nonzero()].max().eval()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#146>", line 1, in <module>
    that[~(that>=5).nonzero()].max().eval()
AttributeError: 'TensorVariable' object has no attribute 'nonzero'
```

Why does this happen? Is this a subtle nuance that i'm missing?

Comment: Well, the literal traceback for your second is saying that the array does not have a `nonzero()` method/attribute, so you can't use that in the same way that you would use a numpy array.

Comment: @JeffTratner: Which is opposed to [the example](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#indexing) provided on the website...

Comment: @NoobSailbot are you using the right version?

Comment: @JeffTratner: `theano.version.version` gives me `'0.6.0rc3'`. Is `nonzero()` not supported in that version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using a version of Theano that is too old. In fact, tensor_var.nonzero() isn't in any released version. You need to update to the development version.

With the development version I have this:

```
>>> that[~(that>=5).nonzero()].max().eval()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'tuple'
```

This is because you are missing parenthesis in your line. Here is the good line:

```
>>> that[(~(that>=5)).nonzero()].max().eval()
array(9, dtype=int32)
```

But we still have unexpected result! The problem is that Theano do not support bool. Doing ~ on int8, is doing the bitwise invert on 8 bits, not 1 bit. It give this result:

```
>>> (that>=5).eval()
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int8)
>>> (~(that>=5)).eval()
array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2], dtype=int8)
```

You can remove the ~ with this:

```
>>> that[(that<5).nonzero()].max().eval()
array(4, dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Good stuff, thank you. But i'm a bit confused on what you mean by "development version". Is that the "bleeding-edge" i read about? Isn't that supposed to be experimental?

Comment: @nouiz, I just wanna say, thanks a million for your wonderful answer +1.